# Invalid property value for multiple backgrounds with image and linear-gradient

Tags: css, google-chrome, sass, gradient, linear-gradients

I'm trying to set up a select element with multiple backgrounds (one image, and one linear-gradient). It worked while I was developing, but for some reason it stopped working when it was pushed to production.

Here's the code I started with (in SCSS):

```
$select-arrow-uri: 'data:image/png;base64,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';

select{
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    background-image: url("#{$select-arrow-uri}");
    background-image: url("#{$select-arrow-uri}"), -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #e5e5e5 0%, #f5f5f5 100%);
    background-image: url("#{$select-arrow-uri}"), linear-gradient(#e5e5e5 0%, #f5f5f5 100%);
    background-position: 95% center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

and this is how it is appearing in the browser:

```
background:url(data:image/png;base64,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) 95% center no-repeat,
linear,to bottom,#e5e5e5,#f5f5f5;
```

When I remove the background-image rule with linear-gradient, it works fine. It doesn't have any problems with the -webkit-linear-gradient line, just the linear-gradient line.

Is there a syntax issue? Could Sass be compiling weird? Is it trouble with the URI string?

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: Hmm that's a quandary. I tried compiling and building this and everything worked fine. Is your compiler combining everything under `select` in your sass file into the `background` shorthand?

Comment: Your suggestion got me going down the right path. Check out my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. I have the Bourbon library loaded, and there is a function for linear-gradient that is made to work with the background-image mixin, and that was being used without using the background-image mixin. I switched to the background-image mixin to get it to work, but I'll probably report this to them. Not cool Bourbon.